# Why I can not execute any codes on R script, but still can execute them on R console?

Tags: r, command, rstudio, execute, rscript

Problem is that I can not execute any codes on R script, but still can execute them on R console.

One more thing is when I open Rstudio, there's always a notification saying "The "git" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?"
However, when I clik "install", I always get the noti saying "Can't install the software because it's not available from Software update server."

I'm using MacOS Catalina 10.15.6, and installed R-4.0.2.pkg and Rstudio-1.3.1093.dmg.
Please tell if there's anything I can do to fix these?

Comment: what does "can not execute any codes on R script" mean? Nothing happens when you press "Source", or run `source("my_script.R")`?

Comment: It means that when I type, for example "1/2", on Rscript from Rstudio, then click "Run", or press "Enter", no calculation is done in R console below.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ALt+Ctrl+R** to run the code from the script. (It is a command to run all lines in the R script) or you can select Code(it is on the right side of File option on the top) and then select Run Region and then Run All.

Comment: The OP states they are using a Mac, which doesn't have ctrl or alt (although.an equivalent is available). When posting an answer, please ensure you have replicated the OP's issue and/or tested the solution.